# DDD Root Aggregate with nested entities

Tags: c#, nested, domain-driven-design

### Scenario

| Warning: I omit part of the code for better readability (i.e. public/private setter, etc)

I have:

```cs
class Configuration : RootAggregate
{
     public string code;

     // other fields

     public List<Group> Groups;
}

class Group : Entity
{
     public string: code;
     
     // other fields

     public List<Characteristic> Characteristics;
}

class Characteristic : Entity
{
     public string: code;
     
     // other fields

     public List<Value> Values;
}

class Value : ValueObject
{
     public string code;
     public string value;
}
```

So I have a RootAggregate with nested entities.

Configuration 1
__ Group up to 10
______ Characteristic up to 150
__________ values up to 50

What I have done:

#### 1st solution

All together and pass the entity as a parameter to the methods (instead of primitives)

What I don't like: to update a single characteristic's value I must first load ALL groups and related characteristics and worry about performance and complexity, also on the repository, I must have methods for updating the entire Configuration with related entities, for the single characteristic's value I must query for all, then update the characteristic and then persist the **Configuration** loop through all entities and *reconcile* with DB.

```cs
class Configuration : RootAggregate
{
     public string code;

     // other fields

     public List<Group> Groups;

     public void AddGroup(Group group)

     public void UpdateGroup(Group group)

     public void RemoveGroup(string code)
}

class Group : Entity
{
     public string: code;
     
     // other fields

     public List<Characteristic> Characteristics;

     public void AddCharacteristic(Characteristic characteristic)

     public void UpdateCharacteristic(Characteristic characteristic)

     public void RemoveCharacteristic(string code)
}

class Characteristic : Entity
{
     public string: code;
     
     // other fields

     public List<Value> Values;

     public void CreateValue(string code, string value)

     public void UpdateValue(string code, string value)

     public void RemoveValue(string code)
}
```

#### 2nd solution

Split the Configuration from the Group (or Configuration-> Group and split Characteristics -> Values)

What I don't like: -> This violates the DDD principle since I must validate the Group (for double code) **BEFORE** add to Configuration.

```cs
class Configuration : RootAggregate
{
     public string code;

     // other fields


}

class Group : RootAggregate
{
     public string ConfigurationId;

     public string: code;
     
     // other fields

     public List<Characteristic> Characteristics;

     public void CreateCharacteristic (string code, <other fields>, IEnumerable<Value> values)

     public void UpdateCharacteristic (string code, <other fields>, IEnumerable<Value> values)

     public void DeleteCharacteristic (string code)
}

class Characteristic : Entity
{
     public string: code;
     
     // other fields

     public List<Value> Values;

     public SetValues(List<Value> values);
}

class Value : ValueObject
{
     public string code;
     public string value;
}
```

NB I have already read this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889425/creating-nested-entities-through-an-aggregate-root-ddd) but I think is not applicable in this scenario.

### Question

What is the approach to the DDD pattern with a Root Aggregate and N nested level of entities?

What is the *best* solution in this particular scenario?

What is the `IRepository` structure to persist the selected solution?

Answer (score 1):

To tell you what is the proper aggregate I'd like to know business requirements, not your structure. What harms you in the first solution actually is known as best practices in DDD (to keep consistency you are obligated to eagerly load aggregate root with ALL its nested entities).

What I deduce from your code it is that inside there is the following business rule:
`Configuration` should not have duplicated `Codes`.

If you want to model it as an aggregate root then I'd keep in the `Configuration` only that data, that is REALLY needed to keep your invariant consistent - so it might keep only `codes` without values. Hence example code utilizing refined model:

```
public void addCode(ConfigurationId configurationId, string code, string value){
   Configuration configuration = configRepo.Fetch(configurationId);
   configuration.AddCode(code);
   Value value = new Value(code, value);
   configRepo.Save(configuration);
   valueRepo.Save(value);
}
```

and then you can manipulate values without having to worry about optimistic locking and invariant being broken in such a way:

```
public void updateValue(string code, string newValue){
   Value value = valueRepo.fetch(code);
   value.innerValue = newValue;
   valueRepo.save(value);
}
```

However it is just guessing since I do not know your exact invariants. If you provide them then I'll be able to refine aforementioned code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I dig deep into the problem and I understand that I don't understand ;-). I read this [pdf from Vernon](https://www.dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_1.pdf) there are three [pdf](https://www.dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/).  I also read this very well-written [article](https://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2013/10/18/Modelling-Aggregate-Roots-Relationships.aspx) about root aggregate. My solution is to have three different root aggregates and use a Domain Service to validate the duplicate codes.

Answer (score 0):

Deep hierarchies are not ideal when implementing a domain model.  Conceptually the hierarchy is there but it doesn't mean that you cannot split it up into distinct aggregates in your domain model.

For the read side of things your presentation layer would, in all probability, still visualize the hierarchy as what seems to be a single thing.

I would definitely go with your second approach.

Anything that is required to have consistency, such as your non-duplicate group code invariant, you'd pull into the appropriate aggregate.  You can represent that with identifiers, or value objects, in the containing aggregate.